# Unrecognized selector sent to UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

hoping you can help me out. Code is Rubymotion but I'm pretty sure it's an iOS issue.  Code is simple enough that hopefully it being Rubymotion doesn't get in the way of an answer.  And I can read Obj-C, so if you can answer with Obj-C only, I'm good with that.

I have a UIImage object. I'm trying to get the size of it.  When I do the following:

```
image = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) 
@image = UIImage.alloc.initWithCIImage(image)
puts @image.to_s
puts @image.size
puts @image.to_s
```

I get this output:

```
#<UIImage:0x9513710>
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[UIImage extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10fb7410 (RuntimeError)
#<UIImage:0x9513710>
```

I've read that when you get the extent error, it tends to mean the object has been released and is no longer in memory but if I comment out the .size line, the 3rd line still runs meaning it hasn't been released.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is UIImage is not finding a method called extent.

Comment: I'm not calling extent.

Comment: @DanBrooking `extent` is getting called somewhere on a `UIImage`. There is no error called `extent error` the error is `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. `UIImage` is the object and `extent` is a method/function that is being called on that object. If it were an error where an object has been released than you would get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. You need to show your code relating to the `UIImage` object.

Comment: I added the code where I declare the image var.  Nothing special about image... it's just a plain old UIImage instance.

Comment: Also, I know what the error means. I just don't understand why I'm getting it.

Comment: @DanBrooking Your question gives the impression you don't know what it means from this comment in your question    "I've read that when you get the extent error, it tends to mean the object has been released and is no longer in memory but if I comment out the .size line, the 3rd line still runs meaning it hasn't been released."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere you are using the UIImage instance rather than the CIImage instance... CIImage has a function called "Extent" on it (from a quick google) and UIImage doesn't. Maybe you're passing the image to a function which is using this "Extent" function.

Comment: But once I do this:
    `@image = UIImage.alloc.initWithCIImage(image)`
won't that be good? image is coming back as class UIImage so I'm not sure why doing
    `@image.size`
would give this error

Comment: Well then it seems that RubyMotion is the root of the problem, RubyMotion appears to be translating the function .size into extent: I'm afraid that's the only help I can offer!

Comment: OK... so your answer made me think... I went digging through some old code and modified my call to size to be this: `@image.CIImage.size` and it works fine.  So..... thanks for leading me down the path to the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dave for leading me to this answer.  The code needs to be written as
    `@image.CIImage.size`

This will work.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? Seems more like a comment for DaveLevertons answer.

Comment: I was giving the specific answer to my question and was going to mark it as the answer... but then decided since the actual answer was so simple, I'd just give Dave the credit and mark his response as the answer.